# ntdll.dll error using plplot, VS 2017 and Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, plplot

All,

I recently needed a new drive in an old computer and after reinstalling all my s/w have the following issue.

I am developing applications on a Windows 8.1 machine using VS 2017 enterprise edition, wxWidgets, plplot, and various other open source code (e.g. Eigen, boost, etc).

The build and install of plplot was not without issue but after some work and help from the plplot POCs I was able to get it to install without an error.  Now I'm running the examples just to be sure things work as expected.  It seems that the examples provided by plplot do run as expected but upon closing them it crashes.  Using the debugger I get the following error,

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB1C8D1340 (ntdll.dll) in plplotExamples.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FFB1C90DD50).

This seems to occur whenever there is a delete of the plot stream, delete pls;.

I did some web searches leading to stackoverflow and tried all I can to get info on this issue.  There does not seem to be any issue with the dll, memory issues, or any other issue caught by diagnostic checks.

Looking for any suggestions to better understand this issue and how to fix it.
These examples worked prior to the new drive and reinstalling s/w so I'm guessing a bad install of something, or incorrect system parameter, path variable, etc setting, but not sure where to look.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The problem of heap corruption is usually caused by memory access overrun and deletion. Because the two segments of memory you allocate may just be continuous, the first segment of memory crosses the boundaries when it is written, and at the beginning of second segment, some of the heap data is destroyed. So it's wrong to report heap damage. I think it's very similar to your question. This seems to occur whenever there is a delete of the plot stream, delete pls; Check here. What you delete when the program exits is the cause of your problem. It doesn't have much to do with your environment.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess what's confusing to me is that (1) these examples came with plplot and (2) they worked before.